# Reverting Perforce workspace

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I created my own workspace in p4v.
Sometimes bad changelists (CLs) affecting the build and Depot get submitted. So, while working on my workspace after syncing I will encounter these problems with errors.

Example: I know up to CL 100 is good but CL 101 is error causing but submitted.
Now I have latest version in my workspace with CL 101..
How to get my entire workspace back to CL 100. Where the changes that happened with CL 101 are not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In P4V, you can right-click the submitted changelist (100) and click "Get..." to sync the workspace to that changelist.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, use the path you are interested in, not the entire depot:

```
p4 sync //depot/path/...@100
```

Comment: means i should run that command in my linux...then it will change automatically.

Comment: Yes, your path may differ, and I assume 100 was just an example

Comment: To avoid the problem with the path part, you can just do `p4 sync @100`, which will sync everything in your client's view to changelist 100.